# ProgressDialog in XmlAdapters sample error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below are the XmlAdapters sample code. When i add the ProgressDialog as show below receive an error 'The method loadCursorAdapter(Context, int, String, Object...) in the type Adapters is not applicable for the arguments (new AsyncTask(){}, int, String)'

```
       final ProgressDialog _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            _progressDialog.setTitle("Loading ...");
            _progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
             protected Void doInBackground(Void ... urls) {
             setContentView(R.layout.photos_list);
             setListAdapter(Adapters.loadCursorAdapter(this, R.xml.photos,
            "content://xmldocument/?url=" + Uri.encode("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/featured?max-results=50&thumbsize=144c")));
             }

             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 _progressDialog.dismiss();
             }

             protected void onPreExecute(Void no) {
                 _progressDialog.show();
             }

            }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'The method loadCursorAdapter(Context, int, String, Object...) in the
>   type Adapters is not applicable for the arguments (new AsyncTask(){},
>   int, String)'

means loadCursorAdapter take Application or Activity Context as first param instead of AsyncTask so change your code as :

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
      protected Void doInBackground(Void ... urls) {
         setContentView(R.layout.photos_list);
         setListAdapter(Adapters.loadCursorAdapter(Your_Current_Activity.this,
           R.xml.photos,
            "content://xmldocument/?url=" + Uri.encode("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/featured?max-results=50&thumbsize=144c")));
                      //your code here...
```

and i'm not sure this will work becuase you are trying to accessing Ui elements from doInBackground method of AsyncTask whcih always exectue in Background Thread.

you will need to move all Ui related code in `onPostExecute` to update Ui after background execution complete

Comment: I try your code but prompt me another error 'This method must return a result of type Void'.

Comment: @MayWong : add add `return null` in doInBackground method